# JAAS: Make application use Tomcat authentication settings

Tags: authentication, tomcat, jaas

Is it possible to make a web application which uses JAAS authenticate via tomcats default authentication method.

To illustrate: Tomcat uses the tomcat_users.xml for authentications. The web application has defined its own method in jaas.cfg. How do we configure the jaas.cfg in such a way that it uses the Tomcat's method in so that when the configuration in Tomcat changes the application's authentication method switches aswell.

Current config looks like this:

```
BonitaAuth {

  org.ow2.bonita.identity.auth.BonitaIdentityLoginModule required;

};



BonitaStore {

  org.ow2.bonita.identity.auth.LocalStorageLoginModule required;

};



BonitaAuth-default {

  org.ow2.bonita.identity.auth.BonitaIdentityLoginModule required domain="default";

  org.ow2.bonita.identity.auth.LocalStorageLoginModule required domain="default";

};



BonitaStore-default {

  org.ow2.bonita.identity.auth.LocalStorageLoginModule required domain="default";

};



/**

 * Used by the REST server

 */

BonitaRESTServer {

  org.ow2.bonita.identity.auth.BonitaRESTServerLoginModule required logins="restuser" passwords="restbpm" roles="restuser";

};
```

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

The Tomcat user repository is defined by Tomcat Realms.
The tomcat_users.xml file is used by `MemoryRealm`. 
To use your JAAS configuration (jaas.cfg) configure `JAASRealm`: 
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JAASRealm

It is possible to use Java EE authentication and implement your own realm. 
You have 3 options:

1. implement Tomcat `Realm` interface
   http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Realm.html
2. Extend `RealmBase` 
   http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/RealmBase.html)
3. Extend `JAASRealm`
   http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/JAASRealm.html

Configure your own realm in server.xml

```
<Realm className="org.myrealm"/>
```

Tomcat will call to your authenticate  method http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/RealmBase.html#authenticate%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

In the method you can call your JAAS authentication.

Comment: In that manner I make Tomcat use JAAS. Which I don't want. I want a application (that uses JAAS)which is deployed in Tomcat make use of the realm configured in Tomcat.

Comment: I am confusing. 
Do you want to use JEE authentication?
In his case the request hat come to your application already authenticated. 
If not do you want to pragmatically call to JAAS authentication? it is not a big problem. In this case how you will get a user name and a password?